# When running Async/Await code in winform it Block Winform UI, but works when ran in console mode

Tags: vb.net, async-await, synchronization

i have a piece of code i created that works fine when ran from a console app, and doesn't when the project is a winform app. Here is the code below it uses a library u can grab from 'nuget' called [bandwidth 3.1.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bandwidth.Net), this library allows u to make call to their rest API using that library to send SMS test messages, etc. I create this function to run asynchronously hoping to fixed issue when ran in synchronously mode when ran from the winform app it locks up seems it does the same when ran async or i just didn't do something right?

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets a list of your numbers.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="size">Optional: Used for pagination to indicate the size of each page requested for querying a
''' list of phone numbers. If no value is specified the default value is 25. (Maximum value 1000)</param>
''' <param name="name">Optional: Used to filter the retrieved list of numbers allocated for the authenticated user by it’s name.</param>
''' <param name="applicationId">Optional: Used to filter the retrieved list of numbers by an associated application ID.</param>
''' <param name="state">Optional: Used to filter the retrieved list of numbers allocated for the authenticated user by a US state.</param>
''' <param name="city">Optional: Used to filter the retrieved list of numbers allocated for the authenticated user by it’s city.</param>
''' <param name="numberState">Optional: Used to filter the retrieved list of numbers allocated for
''' the authenticated user by the number state. <seealso cref="Bandwidth.Net.Api.PhoneNumberState"/></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Async Function GetListOfPhoneNumbers(ByVal size As Integer?, ByVal name As String, ByVal applicationId As String,
    ByVal state As String, ByVal city As String, ByVal numberState As Api.PhoneNumberState?) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of List(Of Api.PhoneNumber))

    Dim objClient As New Client(CommonApplication.BandWidth_USER_ID,
        CommonApplication.Bandwidth_API_TOKEN, CommonApplication.Bandwidth_API_SECRET)

    Dim objQuery As New Api.PhoneNumberQuery With
        {
            .Size = size,
            .Name = name,
            .ApplicationId = applicationId,
            .State = state,
            .City = city,
            .NumberState = numberState
        }

    Dim objResponse = Await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(
        Function()
            Dim response = objClient.PhoneNumber.List(objQuery)

            Return response.ToList()
        End Function)

    Return objResponse
End Function
```

Comment: How is this not working in a winform app? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No i don't get any errors, it just halt executon, also i ran fiddler to see if it  returned the result from the api that it calls, and it does, just gets stuck when ran from a winform based app.

Comment: Where's the code for `objClient.PhoneNumber.List(...)`?

Comment: there is no code, i used a class library downloaded from nuget called 'bandwidth 3.1.5', please click the link above in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i figured it out if anyone else run into the same issue, u can learn about async/await when used in winform by taking a look at:

[Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary